# aphotspot is working but my android device cant connect to the ssid

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I am new to Ubuntu 14.10,I Have successfully created WLAN-Hotspot on my laptop. I have entered the password on my android phone and It was stuck at obtaining IP address for tethering.

I have tried almost everything. I tried installing earlier version of AP-hotspot, tried debugging it, removed hotspot.pid file, tried on editing dnsmasq etc etc.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off firewall with `sudo ufw disable`.